# Can't use slidebar of joint_state_publisher window in Rviz

Tags: urdf, xacro, 3d-visualization, joint-state-publisher, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created a xacro file for my robot arm and successfully visualized it in Rviz with the display.launch launchfile from the urdf_tutorials package. However, i can't slide left or right with the slidebar to control the joint movements in the joint_state_publisher GUI window, the only thing I can click is the randomize button below the slide bars. The robot is then moving accordingly, so I think there is no problem with my xacro file.

I have to mention though that I haven't included collision and inertia tags in the xacro file yet, could this be the reason?

Can anyone tell me why I can't use those slidebars, or how I can fix this problem?
Thanks a lot!! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242996/can%27t-use-slidebar-of-joint_state_publisher-window-in-rviz/) by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2016-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved.
I compared the code of the joint_state_publisher python script in my local package with the code of the python script from source and realized that the part of the GUI code had some discrepancies.
I then used `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-joint-state-publisher` and that fixed the problem.

---

Originally posted by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) with karma: 146 on 2016-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0